# Change the type between str and the name of list

Tags: python

```
L1 = [1,2,3,4]
L2 = [5,6,7,8]
M1 = [9,10,11,12]        

a = input() #user would input '1' or '2'
b = input() #user would input 'M' or 'L'

c = b + a #the outcome would be either 'L1', 'L2' or 'M1'
```

Is there any way to change the type of c from the string to list.

Comment: Not sure what is being asked here, strings are immutable - but not sure if that is your question

Comment: can you explain the question better?

Comment: You *could* use `eval`, but please don't. This sounds like a silly idea.

Comment: do you mean `print(eval(String)[0])`?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the old ["how do I do variable variables"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables) question.

Comment: @mkrieger1 why not `String = list`?

Comment: I don't know, that question wasn't my idea...

Comment: Do you want `String` to be a `str` of the numbers contained in list? `''.join([str(i) for i in l])`

Comment: @Lynsens This question seems like a contrived example. If you posted you *actual use case* instead, you would probably get much more useful advice.

Comment: Why not just `locals()[c]`? Eval is a completely stupid solution in here and the rest of the answers by now are just workarounds that **will** break if you just scale the code a little bit. Preferably instead of accessing `locals()`(or `globals()`) dictionary you should make your own dictionary, let's say `my_stuff = {'L1': [1,2,3,4], 'M1': ...}` and then just get the strings from the input: `c = my_stuff[b+a]` which if `b == 'L' and a == '1'` will be `c == [1,2,3,4]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm considering you have a string answer stored in the variable `c` and you want to access a list with the respective name. With this objective, you can use the python function `eval()`.

From the python docs ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html)) you have that:

> **eval(expression[, globals[, locals]])**
>
> The *expression* argument is parsed and evaluated as a Python expression
>   (technically speaking, a condition list) using the globals and locals
>   dictionaries as global and local namespace.

It means that in your case, eval will get your string check if your python namespace has have variables with this name. The result is the following:

```
c = 'L1'

print (eval(c)) # it will print the list L1 = [1,2,3,4]
```

The code above will get you where you want. Although I have never used in any real use case I had to work with.

*Obs: Thanks for rewriting the question! :)*

Comment: I downvoted because I don't think answering a question where you have to take a wild guess what the question actually is is not a good idea. I also think that you don't teach OP anything of value here, as your solution should not be used in 'real' code.

Comment: Thank you fernandosjp. I have changed my question to make it easier to understand.  Hopefully it could help other beginners like me :)

Comment: You are welcome @Lynsens! I understand the critics though. StackOverflow is the place for questions but we need to make sure they are clear and organized otherwise it won't help other people. I'm sure the critics will help you out asking better questions and learning faster.

Answer (score 2):

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
```

String = list
then String[0]=1

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is add `'li'+'st'` to get `list` which you think will call your `list` variable.

So what you want is

```
list = [1,2,3,4]
String = 'li'+'st' # then here you expect String = List
```

Yes when you do `'li'+'st'` you get `'list'` but you get it as a string not the variable you stored before

If you want to make `String = List` you just type `String = List` nothing fancy it's that simple

P.S. you should chose better variable names, list is callable in python and calling something String is generally bad practice. try using lst and stg for example.